# spacing on hourglass after drawing in console

Tags: java

i need help in resolving a spacing problem in my hourglass task here are the instructions

Instructions

Given the parameters size = n and the character symbol.

You can assume that n is a positive odd number.

The hourglass consists of n lines.

The character symbol will appear a number of times in each line. The symbol will appear n times in the first line. The number of times the symbol printed will be decreased by 2 in each subsequent line until it reaches 1. After that, the number of times the symbol printed will be increased by 2 in each subsequent line until it reaches n again.

Spaces are added to the start and end of each line so that the total width of each line is n and the symbols in each line are aligned at the center of each line.
For outputting, you can use either System.out.print()/println() or IO.output()/outputln().

here is my code :

```
public static void hourglass(int size, char symbol){
         int subtract = (int)Math.floor(size / 2);

        for(int i = size - subtract; i >= 1; i--){

          for(int j=i;j<size - subtract;j++)

              System.out.print(' ');

          for(int j=1;j<=i*2-1;j++)

              System.out.print(symbol);

              System.out.println();
        }

        for(int i = 2; i <= size - subtract; i++)
        {

         for(int j=i;j<size - subtract;j++)
             System.out.print(' ');

         for(int j=1;j<=i*2-1;j++)

             System.out.print(symbol);
             System.out.println();

        } 

      }
```

what i am trying to get right is instruction set five. i have read quite a few post on array fill and \s+ for the removal of spacing but thats not what i am looking for. Basically what i want to do is even out spacing on the left and right of the hourglass after it has been drawn.

her is an example of my problem:

Given the size of hourglass is 3. The expected output of printHourglass():

```
???¶
█?█¶
???¶
```

Your code outputs:

```
█???¶
██?¶
█???¶
```

i have been trying to solve all night and need to submit soon. Just need some tips agains please.[image: screenshot of problem]

i have attached an image just in case the text does not display properly for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you pasted your code in here as it actually is?
Sorry to say, but it is horribly formatted.
Please decide to use brackets always or never, but not sometimes. I would suggest you to use them always, as it makes things much more clear. Also keep a good indentation:

```
public static void hourglass(int size, char symbol){

    int subtract = (int)Math.floor(size / 2);

    for(int i = size - subtract; i >= 1; i--){

        for(int j=i;j<size - subtract;j++){
          System.out.print(' ');
        }

        for(int j=1;j<=i*2-1;j++){
            System.out.print(symbol);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    for(int i = 2; i <= size - subtract; i++)
    {

        for(int j=i;j<size - subtract;j++){
            System.out.print(' ');
        }

        for(int j=1;j<=i*2-1;j++){
            System.out.print(symbol);
        }

        System.out.println();
    } 

}
```

Next thing with your posted code is, I can not verify your output, as I get the following:
(Please note: I used ? as character and a . instead of space for the sake of visibility)

```
//Size 3
???
.?
???

//Size 5
?????
.???
..?
.???
?????
```

**EDIT 1:**
What you need to do is, add the space-adding logic after the character-adding logic.
To find a loop logic, that works, is your job.

```
    for(int i = size - subtract; i >= 1; i--){

        for(int j=i;j<size - subtract;j++){
            System.out.print(' ');
        }

        for(int j=1;j<=i*2-1;j++){
            System.out.print(symbol);
        }

        for(/*find a working loop*/){
            System.out.print(' ');
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    for(int i = 2; i <= size - subtract; i++)
    {

        for(int j=i;j<size - subtract;j++){
            System.out.print(' ');
        }

        for(int j=1;j<=i*2-1;j++){
            System.out.print(symbol);
        }

        for(/*find a working loop*/){
            System.out.print(' ');
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: yes sorry im still learning to code properly so your critic on the formatting is very much appreciated ill work on making it better. You used size 5 to print to console and where you have . is correct but how do i get it to print on both sides of the hourglass

Comment: Your two for-loops have a sequence: 1) Calculate and print the spaces before the characters 2) Calculate and print the characters.
What is missing is the "3) Calculate and print spaces after characters".

Comment: So would it be right to do something like this   System.out.print(symbol + " ")

Comment: No, this would result in every symbol to be followed by a space.
See my edit in my post.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the loop with the help from Korashen and this is what my code looks like and all prints perfectly

the code prints the spacing represented by a . as well as the symbol giving perfect output in my opinion

```
public class hourglass
{
    public static void hourglass(int size, char symbol){
         int subtract = (int)Math.floor(size / 2);

        for(int i = size - subtract; i >= 1; i--){

          for(int j=i;j<size - subtract;j++){          
              System.out.print('.');
            }

          for(int j=1;j<=i*2-1;j++){          
              System.out.print(symbol);
            }

          for(int j = i; j < size - subtract; j++){
             System.out.print('.');
            }

              System.out.println();
        }

        for(int i = 2; i <= size - subtract; i++)
        {

         for(int j=i;j<size - subtract;j++){
             System.out.print('.');
            }

         for(int j=1;j<=i*2-1;j++){         
             System.out.print(symbol);
            }

         for(int j = i; j < size - subtract; j++){
             System.out.print(".");
            }

            System.out.println();
        } 

   }
```